# Prevent Firefox Sync on startup

Tags: firefox, firefox-sync

In Firefox, I have a master password setup for my passwords. I also sync my passwords (and bookmarks, extensions and settings) using Firefox sync.

The annoying thing is that when I start up Firefox, it will *always* ask for my master password after a few seconds. So when I start up Firefox and type a web address or search query, I get interrupted by the password dialog popping up *while* I'm typing. I want to get around this because it is annoying me so much.

Questions:

1. Can I make Firefox sync manually?
2. Alternatively can I make Firefox sync only when I have to enter a password somewhere?
3. Alternatively can I enter a delay value somewhere in *about:config* between starting up Firefox and running Firefox sync?

Comment: Sorry, can't answer this one. But I will say that I don't use sync to manage passwords. I use LastPass which is a much better tool that works across all major browsers. I don't have your issues when using LastPass.

Comment: @Blaise [Sync timers](https://wiki.mozilla.org/QA/Sync/Client/Sync_Timers) could be helpful?? Please note that I haven't tried these. To filter these prefs in bulk use `sync*sch` and/or `sync*int` in about:config.

Comment: @vWil, I tried that before, increasing all sync timers to three hours, but that didn't work. The descriptions also suggest they change the interval between syncing, not delaying the initial sync after start-up.

Comment: @JulianKnight, LastPass does not sync extensions and settings and has an obtrusive interface.

Comment: Hi Blaise, I know it doesn't sync those things which is why I didn't give it as an answer only a comment. Personally, I've had great problems with sync of FF extensions across platforms and across personal/work machines so I tend not to. I only really want to sync bookmarks since LastPass sync's my passwords and more across ALL browsers and ALL platforms. The interface is a matter of choice. The latest FF interface is pretty good actually.

Comment: Oh, and like many, I hate the way you have to set up FF sync. Very unintuitive which is why they are changing it soon.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I asked the same question on Mozilla Support and got [very useful answers](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/986220). 
Answer that worked for me:

- In about:config, create or modify Boolean `services.sync.autoconnect` and set it to `false`.

This may work in a future version of Firefox: Create or modify integer `services.sync.autoconnectDelay` and set it to a delay in seconds. Both settings did not exist for me yet in Firefox 28 beta.