# Using master password without prompt popup in Firefox

Tags: firefox, passwords, password-management

I'm using Firefox and I have set a master password to protect my saved passwords.

From there, each time I visit a website where I have a password saved,
a box appears and is asking for my master password :

Firefox Password Prompt:

[image]

There is many sessions I visit a website where I have a login saved, but I don't need to log in to accomplish a task. In such situation, this pop-up is quite annoying.

Is there a setting or anything other I can apply in Firefox to prevent this pop-up behaviour, while still keeping a master password as protection ?

Comment: Related: [Prevent Firefox Sync on startup](https://superuser.com/q/707230/358758)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Is there a setting or anything other I can apply in Firefox to prevent this pop-up?

1. Goto `about:config`.
2. Change the value of `security.ask_for_password` as appropriate for your needs:

> - `0` (default): Only the first time it's needed
> - `1`: Every time it's needed
> - `2`: Every `n` minutes, where `n` is the value in `security.password_lifetime`.

Source [about:config entries](http://kb.mozillazine.org/About:config_entries)

Comment: Thank you for your answser @DavidPostill ! I don't know If I miss something, but I tried the three possible values and none prevents the pop up from appearing.

Comment: @JuTaX It will always appear at least once ...

Answer (score 1):

"There is many sessions I visit a website where I have a login saved, but I don't need to log in to accomplish a task. In such situation, this pop-up is quite annoying."

I totally agree with you! And the previous answer is not one, although it is repeated everywhere. A workaround for this is to uncheck the box "Ask to save logins and passwords for web sites" in Firefox settings, while leaving the box "Use a master password" checked.

And when you actually want to enter your master password, or record a new password (which is not every day), go to Firefox settings and temporally check the box "Ask to save…".